# Hibernate Tools Reverse Engineering does not agree with Validator

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-tools

Using:

- Hibernate Tools 5.2.x (tried 5.2.0.Final and 5.2.9.Final)
- Hibernate Core-5.2.13.Final.
- Dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
- Spring 5, Spring Boot 2, Gradle

Hibernate tools hbm2java generates this:

```
@Column(name="domain", nullable=false, length=65535)
    public String getDomain() {
    return this.domain;
}
```

But validator complains about this:

```
wrong column type encountered in column [domain] in table [tpd.acl_object]; 
found [text    (Types#LONGVARCHAR)], 
but expecting [varchar(65535) (Types#VARCHAR)]
```

Detail:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema 
 validation: wrong column type encountered in column [domain] in table 
 [tpd.acl_object]; 
 found [text (Types#LONGVARCHAR)], 
 but expecting [varchar(65535) (Types#VARCHAR)]  
 at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateColumnType(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:159)*
```

So what gives? Why is the validator not in agreement with Hibernate Tools?

Some solutions say to add `columnDefinition=“TEXT”` to the get annotation but that cannot be done neither by type mapping nor custom templates. Also, not sure this is a good idea (i.e. to expose the SQL Type up the food chain). So I am guessing the solution is much simpler and I am missing something very obvious because I cannot be the only person using this combination.

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: It clearly says it is expecting varchar but you are sending longvarchar. Try to minimize the length, 65535 is really big.

Comment: Hi @kaanyılmaz, answer is appreciated but I think you should know why this is so: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html  ... the mapping is not the problem and the size is perfect (is a small text field) the problem seems to be the validator and hibernate tools are not in sync on this one. May be a dialect issue or connection parameter. Waiting for hibernate team's answer on this too: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/validator-does-not-agree-with-hibernate-tools-reverse-engineering/313

Comment: Thanks for the edit @MWiesner I'll know better for next time ;-)